# PRISM eventAggregator Subscription not always working when used with filter

Tags: c#, uwp, prism

I have a strange behaviour with the eventsubscription

My constructor:

```
public ZoneViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregatorInstance, IMessagingService messagingServiceInstance, ICachingService cachingServiceInstance, IShellViewModel shellViewModelInstance, IRaumFeldService raumFeldServiceInstance, string Udn, string Name)
{
        eventAggregator = eventAggregatorInstance;
        messagingService = messagingServiceInstance;
        cachingService = cachingServiceInstance;
        shellViewModel = shellViewModelInstance;
        raumFeldService = raumFeldServiceInstance;

        RoomViewModels = new ObservableCollection<IRoomViewModel>();
        ZoneViewModelTracks = new ObservableCollection<ElementBase>();

        this.Name = Name != string.Empty ? Name : "UnassignedRooms".GetLocalized();
        this.Udn = Udn;

        eventAggregator.GetEvent<MuteChangedEvent>().Subscribe(onMuteChanged,
                     ThreadOption.UIThread, false,
                     device => device.MediaDevice.Udn == Udn);

        GetZoneVolumeCommand.Execute(null);
        GetZoneMuteCommand.Execute(null);
        GetCurrentTransportActionsCommand.Execute(null);
        GetTransportSettingsCommand.Execute(null);
        GetMediaInfoCommand.Execute(null);
        GetPositionInfoCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

When initializing my object, the subscription works, but then the event is never fired. I've checked that the publishevent is firing (which is the case)

When I change the code to this (fixed value to compare; the value is the same as the value used for initialisation). The subscription works fine

```
public ZoneViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregatorInstance, IMessagingService messagingServiceInstance, ICachingService cachingServiceInstance, IShellViewModel shellViewModelInstance, IRaumFeldService raumFeldServiceInstance, string Udn, string Name)
{
        eventAggregator = eventAggregatorInstance;
        messagingService = messagingServiceInstance;
        cachingService = cachingServiceInstance;
        shellViewModel = shellViewModelInstance;
        raumFeldService = raumFeldServiceInstance;

        RoomViewModels = new ObservableCollection<IRoomViewModel>();
        ZoneViewModelTracks = new ObservableCollection<ElementBase>();

        this.Name = Name != string.Empty ? Name : "UnassignedRooms".GetLocalized();
        this.Udn = Udn;

        eventAggregator.GetEvent<MuteChangedEvent>().Subscribe(onMuteChanged,
                     ThreadOption.UIThread, false,
                     device => device.MediaDevice.Udn == "MYUDN");
}
```

Alternative I remove the filter at all and check in my Method which works fine as well:

```
public ZoneViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregatorInstance, IMessagingService messagingServiceInstance, ICachingService cachingServiceInstance, IShellViewModel shellViewModelInstance, IRaumFeldService raumFeldServiceInstance, string Udn, string Name)
{
        eventAggregator = eventAggregatorInstance;
        messagingService = messagingServiceInstance;
        cachingService = cachingServiceInstance;
        shellViewModel = shellViewModelInstance;
        raumFeldService = raumFeldServiceInstance;

        RoomViewModels = new ObservableCollection<IRoomViewModel>();
        ZoneViewModelTracks = new ObservableCollection<ElementBase>();

        this.Name = Name != string.Empty ? Name : "UnassignedRooms".GetLocalized();
        this.Udn = Udn;

        eventAggregator.GetEvent<MuteChangedEvent>().Subscribe(onMuteChanged,
                     ThreadOption.UIThread);

        GetZoneVolumeCommand.Execute(null);
        GetZoneMuteCommand.Execute(null);
        GetCurrentTransportActionsCommand.Execute(null);
        GetTransportSettingsCommand.Execute(null);
        GetMediaInfoCommand.Execute(null);
        GetPositionInfoCommand.Execute(null);
}

private void onMuteChanged(RaumFeldEvent args)
{
        if (args.MediaDevice.Udn == Udn)
        {
            // val = "7" />
            if (args.ChangedValues.TryGetValue("val", out string currenttrack) && currenttrack != "0")
            {
                CurrentTrack = Int32.Parse(currenttrack);
            }
        }
}
```

Do you have any idea what causes the problems? What do I make wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In the not working case, which value of `Udn` is passed to the constructor? And is `this.Udn` read-only or mutable (then you probably want to compare to that as opposed to the initial value)?

Comment: Side-note: try _not_ to name fields (underscore camel-case)/properties (pascal-case) in the same way as parameters (camel-case)... in `onMuteChanged`, `Udn` refers to the field/property but in the constructor, `Udn` refers to the parameter.

Comment: The value of Udn is read only... If I check values on onMuteChanged is works fine. The correct values are compared

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. My class is create as follow

```
zoneViewModel = PrismUnityApplication.Current.Container.Resolve<ZoneViewModel>(new ResolverOverride[]
                            {
                                new ParameterOverride("Udn", zoneRenderer.Udn),
                                new ParameterOverride("Name", zoneRenderer.Name),
                            });
```

I now changed to Naming of the parameters as follows:

```
  public ZoneViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregatorInstance, IMessagingService messagingServiceInstance, ICachingService cachingServiceInstance, IShellViewModel shellViewModelInstance, IRaumFeldService raumFeldServiceInstance, string paramUdn, string paramName)
    {
        eventAggregator = eventAggregatorInstance;
        messagingService = messagingServiceInstance;
        cachingService = cachingServiceInstance;
        shellViewModel = shellViewModelInstance;
        raumFeldService = raumFeldServiceInstance;

        RoomViewModels = new ObservableCollection<IRoomViewModel>();
        ZoneViewModelTracks = new ObservableCollection<ElementBase>();

        this.Name = paramName != string.Empty ? paramName : "UnassignedRooms".GetLocalized();
        this.Udn = paramUdn;

        eventAggregator.GetEvent<MuteChangedEvent>().Subscribe(onMuteChanged,
        ThreadOption.UIThread, false,
                     device => device.MediaDevice.Udn == Udn);

        GetZoneVolumeCommand.Execute(null);
        GetZoneMuteCommand.Execute(null);
        GetCurrentTransportActionsCommand.Execute(null);
        GetTransportSettingsCommand.Execute(null);
        GetMediaInfoCommand.Execute(null);
        GetPositionInfoCommand.Execute(null);
    }

zoneViewModel = PrismUnityApplication.Current.Container.Resolve<ZoneViewModel>(new ResolverOverride[]
                            {
                                new ParameterOverride("paramUdn", zoneRenderer.Udn),
                                new ParameterOverride("paramName", zoneRenderer.Name),
                            });
```

Now it works. Thanks to Haukinger pointing in the right direction!

Comment: Another side-note: with `ParameterOverride` you have to be aware that it applies to the _whole_ `Resolve` call, not only to resolving `ZoneViewModel`! If any dependency has a parameter named `paramUdn` or `paramName` this gets overridden, too, which is rarely the desired behavior. With a hand coded factory, you're on the safe side and your code is more explicit and you're a bit less dependent on the container.